# spark.sql.shuffle.partitions & spark.default.parallelism cannot change after spark session has started?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

Just wanted to confirm that this value cannot change after Spark session has started? Basically, once the spark cluster has been initiated and tasks are running, these values are immutable?

The reason is because if we autoscale up, and our vCPU outnumbers our data partition count, there'll be a performance hit. I realize we can simply have more data partitions than vCPUs however, there is a performance hit of ~20% when we have more data partitions than vCPUs.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not immutable. You can change them at any time while the application is running, though changes won't take effect for already submitted queries. BTW, there's also the Adaptive Query Execution (AQE) feature, which is enabled by default as of EMR 5.30. This feature actually encompasses multiple sub-features, but one main thing it does is let you set the initial SQL shuffle partitions to a higher value and have it automatically coalesce down to a lower number of partitions after each shuffle stage, depending on the amount of data being shuffled.

Comment: We have emr 5.33 but still on spark ~ 2.4. whenever I try to change the default parallelism and sql shuffle, in the environment tab in spark ui, it doesn't show updated values, how do we know if it's actually applied?

Comment: Are you seeing the new values take effect when running queries? That's what is important, right? The new values might not show up on the Environment tab (that is, I don't know offhand whether or not they should show up, but it makes sense to me that they would not) because the values shown in the Environment tab come from what is logged in the Spark Event Logs when the application first starts up. (Although maybe the live Spark UI, as opposed to the one shown by the Spark History Server, might be able to show the most up to date values--I don't know.)